# TCPDF - some fonts are extremly slow

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a PDF document rendered with TCPDF

When using the font `Helvetica` it takes ~400ms to render, but if the same document is rendered with `DejaVuSansCondensed` it is very slow ~1.400ms

Why?